# Proving integral Convergence using Monotone Convergence Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

I'm wondering how I can apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

We are given a decreasing sequence of continuous real valued functions $u_n$ that converge (pointwise) to  an upper-semi continuous function $u$ on some ball $B(0,R) \subseteq \mathbb{C}$. We know that for $z \in B(0, R)$ $$u(z)- \int_0^{2\pi}u_n(Re^{i \theta})P_R(\theta,z) d \theta\leq 0$$ on $B(0, R)$. $P_R$ is the Poisson Kernel.

Now we want to show using the Monotone convergence theorem, that $$u(z) -\int_0^{2\pi}u(Re^{i \theta})P_R(\theta,z) d \theta \leq 0$$ also holds. How can we do that, which non-negative increasing sequence do we use?

Comment: How about $-u_n?$

Comment: Its not non-negative right?

Comment: Yeah; you could try to compensate by shifting the functions up by some value like so: $m=\inf_{x\in[0,2\pi], n\in \mathbb{Z}^+}u_n(x),$ so that you're using $m=u_n(x)$ as your functions. You might have to play with your integrals a bit. Or you might have to use $P_R$ in this calculation as well.

Comment: Does the Monotone Convergence Theorem still apply if $u$ is not necessarily $\geq 0$ but only $\geq B$ for some B (i.e. uniformly bounded from below)?